# How to show a JFXDialog for confirm if the user wants to close the window?

Tags: java, javafx

Im using http://jfoenix.com/ for material design in my javafx app and I want to show a confirmation dialog whenever the user wants to close the window. I try this on my own but the JFXDialog does not appear when i click on the X button. What's wrong?

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent loginView = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D r = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loginView, r.getWidth(), r.getHeight()));
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
        JFXDialogLayout layout = new JFXDialogLayout();
        layout.setHeading(new Text("Confirmar"));
        layout.setBody(new Text("¿Está seguro que desea salir?"));
        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(stackpane, layout, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
        JFXButton yeap = new JFXButton("OK");
        yeap.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                dialog.close();
                primaryStage.hide();
            }
        });
        JFXButton nope = new JFXButton("Cancelar");
        nope.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                dialog.close();
            }
        });
        layout.setActions(nope, yeap);
        dialog.show();
    });
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: You have to **consume** the **event** via `event.consume();`inside the Event-Handler, otherwise the dialog gets closed.

Comment: I did it and the program does not close when i click the X but the dialog does not appear. 
    ...
    `layout.setActions(nope, yeap);
    dialog.show();
    event.consume();`
    ...

@Ben

Comment: You need to consume the event at the beginning of the event not the end. iirc.

Comment: @AdamRen i tried it too and the dialog never appears on.

Comment: where those JFXXXXX classes from?  and as @Ben said, `event.consume()` is necessary.

Comment: Looks like JFXDialog comes from jfoenix lib. Maybe the problem is jfoenix specific?

Comment: did you find answer to your question?